# MySql for Excel

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel, conexão

Faço a conexao com o BD, carrega mas ao editar a pasta fica protegida com senha. Tentei colocar a senha do BD e nada. Alguém ja teve esse problema, poderia dar um help?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]